# Which gets executed first? onclick or ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Now, I have a button and I have a validation process taking place in its click [onclick]. I have a web service call and other processes if the validation is successful, which I have in the ng-click. I doubt validation is not taking place.

My Page:

```
<script>
    validate(){

    // my validation code goes here...

}
</script>

<input type="button" id="btnLogin" title="Login" value="Login" onclick="validate();" ng-click="login_authentication();"/>
```

My Controller:

```
$scope.login_authentication = function() {

 // My login code goes here....

        }
```

Comment: I think you should do the validation the angular style validation will always be done before the click of the button.

Comment: It's a good practice to use ng-click instead of onClick in AngularJS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should avoid using `onclick` in angularjs.

For answer of your question `onClick` will be called first
I tried this code which tells that that `onClick` will be called first.

```
<div ng-controller="ControllerZero">
    <button ng-click="angularNgClick()" onclick="jsClick()">Click</button>
</div>

function ControllerZero($scope) {   
     $scope.angularNgClick = function() {
        alert('Angular NG Click');
    };
}

var jsClick = function() {
        alert('js on Click');
    };
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mkdskd/XqDxG/1155/)

Comment: I will accept yours as answer, for you gave an example. And thanks for the tip, Jussi Kosunen. I removed the onlick func.

Answer (score 3):

Ideally you shouldn't be using `onclick` at all in angular if you can avoid it. Run `validate()` in your `ng-click` and then run `login_authentication()` if successful. Alternatively use angular's `ng-form` style validation for your inputs.